# Allow you tube video full screen

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

In my html I have this:

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=0&allowfullscreeen=1">
</iframe>
```

But when I try to make video full screen it says that I can't do this.
How do I fix this?

You can check the example here http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe doesn't go fullscreen too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, when you are using firefox.

```
<iframe src="your_page_url" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"> </iframe>
```

Comment: works? this not works for me, why? i am using a fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try the allowfullscreen like this:

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I found this answer on a previous question which was posted here: [YouTube iframe embed - full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen)