# IFrame allowfullscreen attribute issue for YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ionic-framework, youtube-iframe-api

Application in : Ionic - Cordova - Angular

Issue :
I am unable to play video in landscape mode.

```
<iframe src="YOU-TUBE-VIDEO-URL" style='width:100%;height:100%' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I remove `allowfullscreen` attribute, landscape works fine but full screen option which is available in player is not shown and hence I am unable to view in fullscreen.

Need : Landscape along with fullscreen.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen'

Comment: Nope .. after adding allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen' behaviour is same .. Testing : Android device HTC & Nexus

Comment: Its working now without any change .. is there any fix in player api ? Also - how to check version details for player js file?