# Embedded YouTube videos doesn't work fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube

I have Using Embed tag for my webpage. It is Working But FullScreen Mode Is Doesn't work it.

```
<embed class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8" allowfullscreen="true">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube iframe embed - full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen)

Answer (score 0):

the reason it's blocked is because its in an embed tag, try using `<iframe>` for this:

```html
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

the `<embed>` tag has no support for fullscreen mode, as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

```
Attributes
This element's attributes include the global attributes.

height
The displayed height of the resource, in CSS pixels. This must be an absolute value; percentages are not allowed.
src
The URL of the resource being embedded.
type
The MIME type to use to select the plug-in to instantiate.
width
The displayed width of the resource, in CSS pixels. This must be an absolute value; percentages are not allowed.
```

this does not include the `allowfullscreen` attribute whereas `<iframe>` does.

Comment: This is a clear duplicate, no need to give an answer, unless you're gonna explain WHY embed is not working and iframe is.

Comment: fair enough, i was researching to find the best answer to why its not working anymore. but since i didn't have that kind of answer ready, i wanted to help OP in the first place by making it work

Comment: Then a comment is more suitable :)