# Youtube iframe - 'fullscreen is unavailable'

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am using iframe to play youtube video. It display full screen icon but on click it says 'fullscreen is unavailable'. I am using allfullscreen still it is not working. Below is the code I have tried so far.

Code 1.

```
<iframe width="760" height="415" id={showVid.id} title={showVid.title} src={showVid.link} allowfullscreen allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```

Code 2.

```
<iframe width="760" height="415" id={showVid.id} title={showVid.title} src={showVid.link} allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture fullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which browser you are using you may need alternative settings turned on iframe see: [YouTube iframe embed - full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen) for in depth answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using **https** in the src attribute for youtube, e.g.

```
<iframe allow="fullscreen;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video.id}"></iframe>
```

I was developing locally using a "//www.youtube.com" link and fullscreen would never work for me!

Answer (score -1):

```css
iframe{
 width : 100%
}
```

then using javascript api set the zoom attribute to zoom = 1;