# Blogger template can't play videos on fullscreen

Tags: iframe, fullscreen, blogger

I bought this movie library template for Google Blogger, It uses this feature

"Big Screen Player" On every post, you have to need use below iframe player on HTML tab.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" id="bigframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO-CODE" width="100%"></iframe>
```

but I can't use the fullscreen mode for youtube videos or google drive videos

what I'm missing?
I've try to contact the seller / developer but theres no anwser...

here it is all of his work:https://www.templatemark.com/search?&max-results=9
all templates this developer is selling have the same problem

here is the demo blogger frontend:
https://demotemplatemovie.blogspot.com/2021/07/test-post-1.html

please if you need access to the edit ask.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `allow="fullscreen"` inside the `iframe` tag. Or other tags you can use according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen#27784769) are:

```
allowfullscreen

mozallowfullscreen

msallowfullscreen

oallowfullscreen

webkitallowfullscreen
```

**Sample** (You can try it somewhere else as Stack Overflow's compiler is facing issues playing it):

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGk2EfbD_Ps" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

****UPDATE:****
Add `allowfullscreen` in the `var c` of the jquery, such that:

```
$(function() {
    if ($("#bigframe").length > 0) {
        var a = $(".single-post-title").text();
        $("#titlevid").text(a);
        var b = $("#bigframe").attr("src");
        var c = '<iframe src="' + b + '" id="covervideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        $(c).appendTo("#myvideo");
        $("#bigframe").remove();
    } else $("#myvideo").remove();
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply

I've tried and this and It doesn't work... I need to have the id="bigframe" in the code to be able to activate the "Big Screen Player" I think this is the problem...

Comment: Please have a look at the updated portion of the answer, this might solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry but this also didn't work...

if you want I can share my blog back end access with you, just send me your email.

thanks again

Comment: Actually, I tried the updated solution with your blog and it was working fine. Maybe you can change the jquery code from the Blogger theme code. And, actually I am not good at back end processes and I do not think that the problem is with the back end service.

Comment: Thanks iamabdm, It worked, I've to change the jquery code from the Blogger theme html code, like you said, thanks again for your help.